# React Router Dom v6 with Typescript: no exported member for Location and NavigateFunction

Tags: typescript, react-router

I want to pass the function returned by useNavigate and the instance returned by useLocation to another function using Typescript. However, their types: Location and NavigateFunction are not exported members of react-router-dom. Am I doing this wrongly?

Context is

- I want to separate the actual redirection behaviour from the react component
- This way, it's easier for me to test

Here's a sample

```js
import { Location, NavigateFunction, useLocation, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

const myRedirectCallback = (location: Location, navFunc: NavigateFunction) => () => {
  // do something here and redirect afterwards
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navFunc = useNavigate();

  const onClick = myRedirectCallback(location, navFunc);

  return <div onClick={onClick}>Click me!</div>;

}
```

Using:
react-router-dom: v6.3.0
typescript: 3.0.1

Comment: Works here: https://tsplay.dev/NByOdw what version of react router are you trying to use?

Comment: Can't reproduce with latest `react-router-dom` v6.3.0

Comment: It should work, which version of `react-router-dom` is in your package.json ?

Comment: I'm using v6.3.0

Could it be because of my old Typescript version? Still using 3.0.1

Comment: Yes, it does fail in typescript 3.3. https://tsplay.dev/mbBM2m That's pretty old and react-router doesn't look like it supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router's types are not compatible with Typescript 3.0.1 (which was released [4 years ago](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-0/))

You'll need to upgrade to a more modern version of typescript to use types from this library.